# Perl split list on commas except when within brackets?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a database with a number of fields containing comma separated values. I need to split these fields in Perl, which is straightforward enough except that some of the values are followed by nested CSVs contained in brackets that I do not want to split.

Example:

```
recycling, environmental science, interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics), consumer education
```

Splitting on ", " gives me:

```
recycling
environmental science
interdisciplinary (e.g.
consumerism
waste management
chemistry
toxicology
government policy
and ethics)
consumer education
```

What I want is:

```
recycling
environmental science
interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics)
consumer education
```

Can any Perl regex(perts) lend a hand?

I have tried modifying a regex string I found in a similar SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566035/how-can-perl-split-a-line-on-whitespace-except-when-the-whitespace-is-in-doubleq) which returns no results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = q{recycling, environmental science, interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics), consumer education};

my @parts = $s =~ m{\A(\w+) ([0-9]) (\([^\(]+\)) (\w+) ([0-9]) ([0-9]{2})};

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@parts;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please make an effort on your own first, then ask questions showing what you have done.

Comment: You can't use a regular expression to parse nested expressions. You need a full-fledged parser.

Comment: You might have a look at [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) and see if you can tweak it to do what you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $s = q{recycling, environmental science, interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics), consumer education};

my @parts = split /(?![^(]+\)), /, $s;
```

Comment: I just found the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481345/perl-split-and-regular-expression) and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution you have chosen is superior, but to those who would say otherwise, regular expressions have a recursion element which will match nested parentheses. The following works fine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = q{recycling, environmental science, interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics), consumer education};

my @parts;

push @parts, $1 while $s =~ /
((?:
  [^(),]+ |
  ( \(
    (?: [^()]+ | (?2) )*
  \) )
)*)
(?: ,\s* | $)
/xg;


print "$_\n" for @parts;
```

even if the parentheses are nested further. No it's not pretty but it does work!

Comment: @borodin how do i add check for {}, [] brackets as well apart from ()

Comment: @zubug55: You need to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

Did anyone say you have to do it in one step?
You could slice of values in a loop. Given your example you could use something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = q{recycling, environmental science, interdisciplinary (e.g., consumerism, waste management, chemistry, toxicology, government policy, and ethics), consumer education};

my @parts;
while(1){

        my ($elem, $rest) = $s =~ m/^((?:\w|\s)+)(?:,\s*([^\(]*.*))?$/;
        if (not $elem) {
                say "second approach";
                ($elem, $rest) = $s =~ m/^(?:((?:\w|\s)+\s*\([^\)]+\)),\s*(.*))$/;
        }
        $s = $rest;
        push @parts, $elem;
        last if not $s;

}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@parts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that uses loops and `split`. I haven't tested the performance, but shouldn't this be faster than the look-ahead regexp solutions (as the length of `$str` increases)?

```
my @elems = split ",", $str;
my @answer;
my @parens;
while(scalar @elems) {
    push @answer,(shift @elems) while($elems[0] !~ /\(/);
    push @parens, (shift @elems) while($elems[0] !~ /\)/);
    push @answer, join ",", (@parens, shift @elems);
    @parens = ();
}
```