# PHP: Split Complicated String

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to write a function that will take a string and create a drop down list.

Here is an example string:

```
Primary[Blue|0000FF,Red|FF0000,Yellow|FFFF00],Secondary[Green|00FF00,Orange|FF9900,Purple|663399],Brown|A52A2A,Silver|C0C0C0
```

That I want to turn into this:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Primary">
<option value="0000FF">Blue</option>
<option value="FF0000">Red</option>
<option value="FFFF00">Yellow</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Secondary">
<option value="00FF00">Green</option>
<option value="FF9900">Orange</option>
<option value="663399">Purple</option>
</optgroup>
<option value="A52A2A">Brown</option>
<option value="C0C0C0">Silver</option>
</select>
```

I've been trying to convert the string to something like this:

```
[0] => Primary
[0][0] => Blue|0000FF
[0][1] => Red|FF0000
[0][2] => Yellow|FFFF00
[1] => Secondary
[1][0] => Green|00FF00
[1][1] => Orange|FF9900
[1][2] => Purple|663399
[2]
[2][0] => Brown|A52A2A
[3]
[3][0] => Silver|C0C0C0
```

I'm not sure how to split the initial string.  I tried explode and preg_split, but neither seem to split where I need it to.

Comment: your string's pattern is not consistent.

Comment: Maybe just use json syntax?

Comment: `explode( '],', $string )` will get an array containing `[0] => "Primary[Blue|0000FF,Red|FF0000,Yellow|FFFF00", [1] => "Secondary[Green|00FF00,Orange|FF9900,Purple|663399", [2] => "Brown|A52A2A,Silver|C0C0C0"` From there, you could explode each of those on "[", and the results from that can be exploded on ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you ended up with this string for i 'll advice you to consider `json_decode` and `json_encode`

For the current format you can use :

```
$string = 'Primary[Blue|0000FF,Red|FF0000,Yellow|FFFF00],Secondary[Green|00FF00,Orange|FF9900,Purple|663399],Brown|A52A2A,Silver|C0C0C0';
preg_match_all("/([a-z]+)(\[([a-z0-9|,]+)\])|([a-z0-9|,]+)$/i", $string, $m);

printf("<select>");
for($i = 0; $i < count($m[1]); $i ++) {
    if (! empty($m[1][$i])) {
        printf("\n\t<optgroup label=\"%s\">", $m[1][$i]);
        foreach ( array_filter(explode(",", $m[3][$i])) as $var ) {
            list($color, $hex) = explode("|", $var);
            printf("\n\t\t<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $hex, $color);
        }
        printf("\n\t</optgroup>");
    }
}
foreach ( array_filter(explode(",", $m[4][2])) as $var ) {
    list($color, $hex) = explode("|", $var);
    printf("\n\t<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $hex, $color);
}
printf("\n</select>");
```

Output

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Primary">
        <option value="0000FF">Blue</option>
        <option value="FF0000">Red</option>
        <option value="FFFF00">Yellow</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Secondary">
        <option value="00FF00">Green</option>
        <option value="FF9900">Orange</option>
        <option value="663399">Purple</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="A52A2A">Brown</option>
    <option value="C0C0C0">Silver</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split on [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435857): `(?![^\[]+\]),`.

Then from there, see if the string contains `[]`.

```
$array = preg_split('/(?![^\[]+\]),/', $string);

$return = array();

foreach($array as $val){
    if(preg_match('/(.*)\[(.*)\]/', $val, $match) === 1){
        $return[$match[1]] = explode(',', $match[2]);
    }
    else{
        $return[] = $val;
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/BM0ewX