# Split an expression into list based on some silly conditions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, list

I have a some expression like below:

```
^f04[^z]*$ ^f00bar$,^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo bar OR f04ba
```

So, what i want to do here is:

if the 2 consecutive words or  words in the form of regex are separated by spaces then change that space into word AND and if they are separated by ,(comma) change it to word OR and if they are separated by AND and OR leave them as it is.

So, now this should look like:

```
^f04[^z]*$ AND ^f00bar$ OR ^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo AND bar OR f04ba
```

Also, finally if the two words are separated by AND then i want to put a bracket around it, so it will look like below:

```
(^f04[^z]*$ AND ^f00bar$) OR (^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo AND bar) OR f04ba
```

Another example :

1.) `foo bar OR cat AND crap,flu` -> `(foo AND bar) OR (cat AND CRAP) OR flu`

2.) `^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ /k1=v1/ /k2=v2/ bar, cat` ->

```
(^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND /k1=v1/ AND /k2=v2/ AND bar) OR cat
```

Whats the best way to do this?

I was thinking to do it like below:

1. Split the expression by space into list.
   List will look like :

   ```
   [^f04[^z]*$,^f00bar$,',',^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$,AND,foo,bar,OR,f04ba]
   ```
2. Traverse the list, If every alternate word doesn't look like AND,OR or ',' then add AND after that word and if it is ',' then change it to OR.

Is this good? What should be the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Just a detail, but should it be `... OR (... AND ...) OR ...` or `... OR \(... AND ...\) OR ...`?

Comment: Can there be `,` that should not be replaced but interpreted as part of the regex, as in `{2,4}` or `[^,.-]`?

Comment: added examples plz check

Comment: yes, comma part of regex should be treated as part of word.

Comment: I did this in perl with this code: splitting list into words where some words contain comma as part of regex-> my @array;

   ## splitting input expression by comma and storing in an array
   while (
      $exp =~ m{
        ((?:
          [^(),]+ |
          ( \(
            (?: [^()]+ | (?2) )*
          \) )
        )+)
        (?: ,\s* | $)
        }xg
      ) {
      push @array, $1;

Comment: this did split the expression properly, i can use the same in python.

Comment: just saying, if we split list on space then problem of comma part of regex wont occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manipulate your regex using... a regex. First, use `re.split` to split at each `,` *or* `OR` and at each space *or* `AND` respectively.

```
>>> r = "^f04[^z]*$ ^f00bar$,^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo bar OR f04ba"
>>> groups = [[y for y in re.split(" |AND", x) if y] for x in re.split(",|OR", r)]
>>> groups
[['^f04[^z]*$', '^f00bar$'], ['^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$', 'foo', 'bar'], ['f04ba']]
```

Then, just `str.join` those back together and wrap the `AND` groups into `(...)`:

```
>>> ' OR '.join('(' + ' AND '.join(grp) + ')' for grp in groups)
'(^f04[^z]*$ AND ^f00bar$) OR (^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo AND bar) OR (f04ba)'
```

Note, however, that this will split at *all* `,`, even if those should be part of the regex. I don't really see how those should be discriminated. (This might be possible with a more complex regex instead of `,|OR` like the one you've shown in comments, I did not try this.)

Also, this will wrap each part of the conjunction into `(...)` even if those have just one element. That could be fixed by a more complex list comprehension checking the `len` of the group (sans empty elements) first.

```
>>> ' OR '.join('(' + ' AND '.join(grp) + ')' if len(grp) > 1 and len(groups) > 1 
...             else ' AND '.join(grp) for grp in groups)
'(^f04[^z]*$ AND ^f00bar$) OR (^.*f04.*&~(.*z.*)$ AND foo AND bar) OR f04ba'
```

Comment: it's not necessary that comma is always part of an expression -> expression can be as simple as -> foo bar cat -> (foo AND bar AND cat)

Comment: @zubug55 If there is no comma, there's no problem.

Comment: but it shouldn't split at all comma comma which are part of regex should be part of regex only

Comment: the way to split on comma is -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436422/9302655 it's in perl ; do you know how do i do this in python

Comment: In any regex strings like above, comma can only come in {3,6} form right and nothing else?